# Two numbers with a given difference having the same number of divisors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, divisibility, arithmetic-functions

So, it is required to prove that for each natural $k$ there are two natural numbers with a difference $k$ having the same number of divisors. For example, for the case $k=27$, the pair $(18,45)$ is suitable.

One of the special cases of this problem can be solved quite easily, namely, if in the factorization of the number $k$ into factors there is an equal number of twos and triples (in particular, if there are none at all), then the numbers $2k$ and $3k$ will have the same number of divisors.

Please help to solve this problem in the general case.

Comment: to do $k=3^a$  use $2\times 43=5\times 17+1$.  The pair $(2\times 43\times 3^a,5\times 17\times 3^a)$ works.

Comment: For $k=2^a$ use $(5\times 2^{a-1}, 3\times 2^{a-1})$

Comment: @lulu Just to clarify, you still need to deal with cases like $k = 3^a \times 5^b \times 17^c$.

Comment: @Calvin Lin
for your specific example $k=3^a 5^b 17 ^c$ there is simple d,e such that e-d=k
and d,e have the same number of divisors.
for such k if b>0 then define $e=3^a 7\cdot 5^{b-1} 17 ^c,\quad d=3^a 2\cdot 5^{b-1} 17 ^c$ 
its easy to see that e,d satisfy the requirements.
if b=0 but a>0 i.e. $k=3^a 17 ^c$ we can define   $e=5\cdot 3^{a-1}  17 ^c,\quad d=2\cdot 3^{a-1}  17 ^c$ and so on....

Comment: @NivMan Right, I meant to indicate that OP has only accounted for "order of 2 = order of 3", and the cases that remain are more than just $ 2^a 3^b$ for some $ a, b \geq 0$.   $\quad$ More generally, this approach seems like it might result in infinite cases, since you'd still have to deal with when $ k = 3^a5^b17^c7^d$.